# download azure container as zip file asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

i want to download all files in container on azure as zip file and make the path to download be  dynamic
this the right now code

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string[] arr = userName.Split('\\');
        string path = $@"C:\Users\{arr[1]}\Downloads\";
        CloudBlobContainer contianner = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(contianerName);

        var list = contianner.ListBlobs();

       /// Console.WriteLine(list.Count());
        string[] FilesName = new string[list.Count()];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var blob in list)
        {
            string[] Name = blob.Uri.AbsolutePath.Split('/');
            FilesName[i++] = Name[2];
          //  Console.WriteLine(Name[2]);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = contianner.GetBlockBlobReference(Name[2]);
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"{path}ImagesPath");
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite($@"{path}\ImagesPath\{Name[2]}"))
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Base on a date? Based on user input? As is, when you download the user can change the target folder anyway

Comment: don't make hard code to chose the path of download

Comment: Well what do you want to put in there instead? Do you want to load from a config? You have only told what you _don't_ want to do.

Comment: need the user choose the path of download or force the browser to download don't want to write the path in the code

Comment: Now that you have finally explained your requirement: This is a browser based function that you can't override (have you ever downloaded something in a browser and it's shown a popup asking for a path?) You _could_ use a client side prompt to accept a path beforehand then send it as a parameter to this method. But the method you have posted is missing all the web specific code that will allow us to comment on that. This is server side code which cannot prompt a user from the browser. You need to do that with client code (javascript) then pass the result to this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish your job using 3 steps.

Step 1, Download all the files to a folder. I suggest you create a folder under your content folder of your web application.

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storage connection string");

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

string containerName = "mycontainer";

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

var blobs = container.ListBlobs(string.Empty, true);
string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
string directoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + containerName + currentDateTime);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
foreach (CloudBlockBlob blockBlob in blobs)
{
    string[] segements = blockBlob.Name.Split('/');
    string subFolderPath = directoryPath;
    for (int i = 0; i < segements.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        subFolderPath = subFolderPath + "\\" + segements[i];
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(subFolderPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subFolderPath);
        }
    }
    string filePath = directoryPath + "\\" + blockBlob.Name;
    blockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
}

Console.WriteLine("Download files successful.");
```

Step 2, After download the files, we could compress the folder using System.IO.Compression.ZipFile class. To use it, we need to add references to 2 assemblies. System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(directoryPath, directoryPath + ".zip");
Console.WriteLine("Compress the folder successfully");
```

Step 3, Since the zip file is generated in the content folder, you could generate the URL for downloading operation.

```
string url = "http://hostname:port/content/" + containerName + currentDateTime + ".zip";
```

Comment: the access denied to access the path of download

Comment: "Access to the path '~/Content/pictures20170828100934' is denied. "

Comment: Which line of code cause this exception? Please also provide your environment. Did you run your web application on Azure or your local?